# Linphone-android make error

Tags: android, android-ndk, linphone

I follow guild, clone project and run

```
make
```

and get following error:

```
/home/xx/android-ndk-r9/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:59:35: fatal error: sys/system_properties.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [codec/common/cpu-features.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xx/linphone-android/submodules/externals/build/openh264/arm'
make: *** [build-openh264-arm] Error 2
```

I using Ubuntu 14.4, ndk-r9. Anybody help me on this?

Comment: any luck with the this issue? can you please share the solution if you had.

Comment: 4 years old ....linphone and ndk between have evolved... ,sorry must close this question and marked as old not interesting any more ....